# Can I execute a node.js script from a Java Class?

Tags: java, node.js

I am currently developing a Java system that communicates with node.js using socket.io. The system and the script are on the same server. How can I execute the script from my Java code and keep it alive from my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note when using process builder the path to your JavaScript file is an argument and "node" is the command, so they need to be separated:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("node", "app.js");
```

This is also useful for inheriting its console output, starting the process and getting the reference to the process:

```
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 5):

Say you have a node.js script named "mynodejs.js". You can use the following java code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("node mynodejs.js");
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("node mynodejs.js", "-args");
```

Comment: Im having problems executing these comands I always get an error saying that node is not a program but I dont get this error executing from the terminal is my app not reading the environment variables correctly

Comment: Be sure your node.exe is in your system path or you may want to use something like this:
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe mynodejs.js");

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class.

You can start any process on your machine like you would via shell, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Java 7 ProcessBuilder is even better. It allows piping: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html